# How to store array of key => value data in on ORM and allow edits via Sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Coming over from Python to do an application in SF2 and would love some help

I need to create a list of books, this has been easy and Sonata admin bundle has been really easy to setup but now I'm stuck one one section

I need the following fields:

`Title
    ie. Harry Potter
Description
    ie. Book about wizards
Themes

    ie. ['Animals' => ['Donkey', 'Cat'], 'Seasons' => ['Winter', 'Summer']]
Grammar 
    ie. ['Possessive pronoun' => ['my']]`

The Themes and Grammar I would identify as:

`Area
    Target: The target (string)
    Examples: list of examples (array)`

Is there any Doctrine & Sonata admin related data structure that would be good to use in this situation? I do not need the "areas" to be their own models but would like to list each area target and it's examples on a template.

Thankyou!

Comment: Have you read through [the Symfony Doctrine documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html)? It's hard to answer your question because it's too broad!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to store Area as an Entity and also Example as an entity. Then you can make many-to-one relations called "grammar" and one-to-many relation called themes both pointing to Area entity and also one-to-many relation in Area entity that points to Example entity. In Area entity I advise you to write __toString function in Area Entity. This function can return string composed with target and examples. This will let you print Area properly - for example on sonata admin list.

If you build query in Sonata Admin make sure you extend default query with left joins to Area and Example entities.